# How to automate my Python code?

Tags: python, list

```
list1=[1.0,2.0,3.1,4.2]
list2=[3.0,2.0,7.2,5.1,9.2]
list3=[2.1,4.2,5.1,9.2]

su1 = list1 + [x for x in list2 if x not in list1]
su2= su1 + [x for x in list3 if x not in su1]
su2=sorted(su2)
print su2
```

I will  have latter probably more list so I would like to automate my code.

```
list_of_lists= []
list_of_lists.append(list1)
list_of_lists.append(list2)
list_of_lists.append(list3)
```

I have create `list_of lists`.But what to do know,how to loop through it?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). What do you want to accomplish? Keep a sorted datastructure of unique entries?

Comment: @L3viathan Sorted datastructure.

Comment: It might be overkill, but you could look into the [SortedContainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) library (and its `SortedSet`).

Comment: @L3viathan Will try,although both solution suggested work fine for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Your lists goes here
list1 = [1.0, 2.0, 3.1, 4.2]
list2 = [3.0, 2.0, 7.2, 5.1, 9.2]
list3 = [2.1, 4.2, 5.1, 9.2]

# Collect all the lists
list_of_lists = []
list_of_lists.append(list1)
list_of_lists.append(list2)
list_of_lists.append(list3)

# This list will contain the final result
result = []

# Loop the inner lists from list_of_lists, this will be list1, list2, list3...
for inner_list in list_of_lists:
    # Loop each element of the inner lists
    for element in inner_list:
        # Make sure the element is not already in the result (this can also be done with sets)
        if element not in result:
            # Add the inner element to result
            result.append(element)

# Sort the result
result = sorted(result)

# Finally output the list
print result # Outputs: [1.0, 2.0, 2.1, 3.0, 3.1, 4.2, 5.1, 7.2, 9.2]
```

Comment: How about a little explanation there, boss?

Comment: @SterlingArcher Added comments now. A bit too slow on the writing there.

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools
su2 = sorted(set(itertools.chain(*list_of_lists))
```

`itertools.chain` returns a generator that iterates over the elements of each of the lists in turn, and `itertools.chain(*list_of_lists)` is does the same thing here as `x for lst in list_of_lists for x in lst`.

`set` deduplicates them more efficiently than checking for each new value whether it's already in a list

Finally, `sorted` sorts them as in your existing code.